# Get All invalid elements in xml data using python lxml and XSD schema

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xsd, lxml

I wrote a function to validate xml data against an xsd schema.

But it raises exception once for the first invalid element. Is there any way to get all of the invalid elements without changing the xml input data.

```
xsd_doc = etree.parse('SDO.XSD')
xsd = etree.XMLSchema(xsd_doc)
xml = etree.XML(data)
xsd.validate(xml)
parser = etree.XMLParser(schema=xsd, encoding='utf-8')
etree.fromstring(data, parser)
```

Comment: I believe [iterparse](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm) might let you handle each element in turn, rather than raising a single exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml files were posted to a django project later and I handled the validation  problem by using a form.

Comment: *"This code was added..."*. What code? This is not a good answer.

Comment: I tried to rewrite it. Sorry for disturbing. But this is how I tried to fix my problem.